# C++ - operator= self assignment checking

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

```
class Person {
private:
    string name;
    int id;

public:
    Person(string name, int id): name(name), id(id) {}
    const Person& operator=(const Person &another) {
        if (*this == another) // What is the problem here?
            return *this;
        // do copy
        return *this;
    }
};
```

I want to make a operator= overloading function. In the self assignment checking, if I do the checking as above, it will show error saying `Invalid operands to binary expression (Person and const Person)`. But if I do `this == &another`, no error will be shown.
Is the error saying that type of `this` and type of `another` are different? But if so, how come `this == &another` will work?

Comment: You're trying to call `operator==`, which is not generated for you, so you must have written but have not shown. There is a built-in equality operator for pointers.

Comment: In my experience, it is better to make the assignment operator be self-assign safe rather than to optimize for the pathological case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `*this == another` you are trying to check whether both objects have the same value. For this to work, you have to define the `operator==` for `Person`. That is, `Person::operator==()` will determine whether two `Person` objects have the same *value*.

However, since you want to protect against self-assignment, what you really need is to compare the *identity* of both objects – as opposed to their *value*. You can achieve this by comparing their addresses in memory, i.e.:

```
if (this == &another) // Is "another" the same object?
   return *this; // skip assignment
```

The operands to this `operator==` are pointers to `Person`, not `Person` objects.

Answer (score 2):

Self assignment checking is done by comparing *addresses* of the two objects

```
if (this == &another)
```

C++ has a built in `operator==` for pointers of the same type.

Your code is comparing the *values* of the two objects, and clearly you haven't defined `operator==` for your `Person` class.

But comparing the values is not the right thing to do because there's no special action needed when you are assigning two objects which have the same value, but sometimes there is when you are assigning two *identical* objects.

In fact there's no need in the class you have shown to do any self-assignment testing. Simply this is OK

```
Person& operator=(const Person &another) {
    name = another.name;
    id = another.id;
    return *this;
}
```

Don't think that testing for self-assignment is any kind of efficiency gain, because self-assignment is rare. So if you can avoid the test, then generally you should.

Also worth saying that the generally prefered method for assignment is the [copy and swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom) which also doesn't require any self-assignment testing.